# Dots in lists with mixed-width items

Tags: technical-writing, punctuation

It is common to omit end-dots in lists with very short items:

```
Shop list:

* Milk
* Bread
* Probably eggs
```

It is common to use end-dots in lists with long descriptive items:

```
Things which should be researched for my research:

* Blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah.
* Blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah.
* Blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah.
```

But what about 50/50 case?

```
Some list:

* Blah blah.
* Blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah.
* Blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah.
* Blah blah.
* Blah blah.
* Blah blah.
```

Some another example for 50/50 case:

```
Shop list:

* Buy milk and bread.
* Buy eggs. Hmm... Or maybe meat instead. What is better? I need to think about it some more.
* Buy wine.
* Buy cheese. Nota bene: it should have large holes in it. Never buy a cheese with small holes. Never.
* Buy tomatoes.
* Buy bottled water.
```

Should we use dots here? Should we avoid it? Or should we use them for items 2 and 3 only? What is the common/best practice?

Comment: are the elements in the 50/50 case syntactically independent sentences?

Comment: @NofP I added "real-life" example for 50/50 case.

Comment: Consistency is more important that the style you choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the elements are independent sentences, as in your example, then you should use full stops. An example:

> In the present article we prove that:
>   * our model is correct.
>   * The model by other authors is not correct. Such model also shows some other issues, discussed below.
>   * Collecting data is a difficult and laborious task.

In some situations such as having slightly related sentences, you may use semicolons. An example:

> In the present article we prove that:
>   * our model is correct;
>   * the model outperforms other models;
>   * small variations to the model do not affect performance.